# Does a confusion matrix have to sum to 100% for each class?

Tags: confusion-matrix

[image]

Does my confusion matrix looks correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the confusion matrix is normalized based on the total number of examples. Therefore the sum of all percentages does equal 100% (`38.47 + 9.99 + 3.06 + 48.48 = 100`). The [scikit-learn confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) has different options for the normalization, where the number can be normalized over de rows, columns or all samples (or not at all).